Why isn't the integral of the total differential of a function equal to the function?
For example let $w = 2x^3y$
then $$dw = \frac{\partial w}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial w}{\partial y}dy $$
$$\implies dw = 6x^2y\hspace{1.5mm} dx +  2x^3 \hspace{1.5mm} dy$$
Then why isn't it that $$\int dw = \int 6x^2y\hspace{1.5mm} dx + \int 2x^3 \hspace{1.5mm} dy$$
Because this would mean that
$$w = 2x^3y+2x^3 y + C$$
$$w = 4x^3y +C$$
Which is not the original function we started with why is that?

can you try to specify what you mean by "$\int dw$?" Indefinite integrals lose basically all of their meaning in more than one dimension

Just the same meaning as when used when trying to solve a differential equation the limit of the riemann sums over dw

$w' = 6x^2y dx + 2x^3 dy$ is an exact differential equation.  And to solve an exact diff eq you don't just integrate the parts and sum them together.  However, you can say something like  $w = \int 6x^2y\ dx + g(y) = \int 2x^3\ dy + h(x)$

This looks like the same mistake as in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4887777/139123

Look up finding a potential function in the multivariable part of any calculus book.

Expanding on the comment of user317176
When you partially differentiated the original equation with respect to x and y you found two results:
$$ \frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\hspace{1.5mm} and\hspace{1.5mm} \frac{\partial w}{\partial y}$$
Suppose your initial equation had been $w = 2x^3y +y +3x $
$$ \frac{\partial w}{\partial x} =6x^2y+3$$
$$ \frac{\partial w}{\partial y} = 2x^3+1$$
$$\implies dw = (6x^2y+3)\hspace{1.5mm} dx +  (2x^3+1) \hspace{1.5mm} dy$$
When you integrate, you have to integrate them separately (NOT ADD) but get the same result for each one.
$$\int dw = \int 6x^2y+3\hspace{1.5mm} dx = \int 2x^3 +1\hspace{1.5mm} dy$$
As in partial differentiation the other variables are treated as constants any function $\frac{df(y)}{dx}$ = 0 so when you integrate the constant of integration for this must include f(y)
Thus:
$$ \int 6x^2y+3\hspace{1.5mm} dx = 2x^3y +3x +f(y)$$
likewise $$\int 2x^3 +1\hspace{1.5mm} dy = 2x^3y +y +f(x)$$
From this you can see that f(x)=3x and f(y)=y for the two equations to be equal. Thus
$$\int dw = 2x^3y+3x+y+C$$
In your case f(x)=0 and f(y)=0, so you just have the constant of integration to add.
